PWM nozzle with Adafruit TIme of FLight Sensor - Nozzle turns fully on after a while
I'm relatively new to this so apologies in advance. I have a raspberry pi4 with a Bete Ehpi pulse width modulatin nozzle and a Adafruit-Vl53l4cd time of flight sensor. Code below is set to control the duty cycle of the spray based on distance measured. It works for a little bit of time then all of a sudden I get the error below and the nozzle becomes fully open, flooding my workspace. When I run my time of flight sensor code alone I have no errors, similarly, when I run pwm nozzle control alone, I get no error, but when combined this issue persists. Any suggestions?
*Error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/240709_simple test_01.py", line 62, in <module>
run_program()
File
"/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/240709_simple test_01.py", line 36, in run_program
d = sensor.distance/2.54
File "/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_vl53l4cd.py", line 213, in distance
dist = self._read_register(_VL53L4CD_RESULT_DISTANCE, 2)
File "/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_vl53l4cd.py", line 455, in _read_register
i2c.write(struct.pack(">H", address))
File
"/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 100, in write
self.i2c.writeto(self.device_address, buf, start=start, end=end)
File
"/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/busio.py", line 212, in writeto
return self._i2c.writeto(address, memoryview(buffer)[start:end], stop=True)
File "/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 60, in writeto
self._i2c_bus.write_bytes(address, buffer[start:end])
File "/home/sppi/SelectivePatina/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 303, in write_bytes
self._device.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error"*

BELOW IS CODE:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_vl53l4cd
#Initialize ToF sensor
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
sensor =adafruit_vl53l4cd.VL53L4CD(i2c)
sensor.start_ranging()
#Initialize GPIO for PWM
PWM_PIN = 18  # Change to your PWM pin
FREQUENCY = 20  # 50 Hz PWM frequency
DUTY_CYCLE_OFF = 0
DUTY_CYCLE_ON = 10  # 20% duty cycle for 9" to 1"
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PWM_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(PWM_PIN, FREQUENCY)
pwm.start(DUTY_CYCLE_OFF)
def stop_program():

raise KeyboardInterrupt#Ctrl+C
def run_program():

try:

    while True:

        while not sensor.data_ready:

            pass

        sensor.clear_interrupt()

        # Measure height

        d = sensor.distance/2.54

        print("Height: {:.2f} inches".format(d))

        #Convert distance to inches (1 inch = 25.4 mm)

        #Control PWM based on distance

        if d > 9:
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(DUTY_CYCLE_OFF)
        elif 1 <= d <= 9:
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(DUTY_CYCLE_ON)
        else:
            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(DUTY_CYCLE_OFF)
            

        time.sleep(0.4)  # Adjust as needed for your application

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
    sensor.stop_ranging()
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(DUTY_CYCLE_OFF)
    pwm.stop()
run_program()
root.mainloop() 


@jsotola all done. Thank you
